# Error in rasterizing a shapefile

Tags: qgis, gdal-rasterize

I tried to convert a polygon shapefile of classified land cover to raster using 'Rasterize (vector to raster) tool in GDAL. I chose the DN field, set output ratser size unit to pixels and chose the same layer extent as output extent. I get the following error:

```
GDAL command output:
*ERROR 1: Wrong value for -ts parameter.
Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]
{[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]
[-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]
[-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def] [-to "NAME=VALUE"]*
*[-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*
[-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
[-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-optim {[AUTO]/VECTOR/RASTER}] [-q]
<src_datasource> <dst_filename>**
```

What should I change to rasterize this polygon?

[image]

Comment: According to your error message you set no extent (`[-te ...]`) and no resolution (`[-ts ...]`).

Comment: Thanks @Erik, but I did set the extent. I attach a screenshot. For resolution, I do not know what I should I choose

Comment: Then simply try some resolutions?

Comment: I tried different valuse but the shapefile is so big and it takes over 1 hour to complete and  I did not know on what base it should be

Comment: You have selected output size units to be in pixels. Width and height are left to zeroes. Zero by zero sized image is nothing. For example 1000 by 1000 pixel sized image would be something.

Answer (score 2):

I created an arbitrary shapefile approximately in your extent area as follows.

[image]

In 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' tool I used following parameters.

[image]

After click in Run, features polygon were rasterized as expected (burn field **class** and resolution 0.1x0.1 degrees).

[image]